# MSNP-SHARP how to send an hello message to an user that changed status from offline to online

Tags: c#, msn, msn-messenger, msnpsharp

I tried in this way. I subscribed to that event who control the user status, its announcing me that user in Online.
my code is:

```
void Nameserver_ContactOnline(object sender, ContactEventArgs e)
{
        Talk = messenger.CreateConversation();
        Talk.Invite(e.Contact.Mail,ClientType.PassportMember);
        Talk.SendTextMessage(new TextMessage(Msg));
        Talk.End();
        LogEvent("Contact online " + e.Contact.Name.ToString() + " " + e.Contact.Mail.ToString());
}
```

someone can give me a hint ? maybe i do something wrong because message wasn't sent.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to use the MessageManager property instead. Make sure you have the latest version of MSNPSharp too.